# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^k = \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that if $(s_n)$ is a convergent sequence, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^k = \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)^k$. Hint: induction.

---

Not sure where to start really... Could anyone give me a hint? We're using Ross' book "Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus," if that helps at all.

Comment: The base case ($k=1$) is obvious, right? Have you learned $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)g(n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$? (when they exist)

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_ny_n = \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n \right)$, use $y_n=x_n^k$ to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^{k+1}= \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)^{k+1}$

Answer (score 0):

I take it you know that is $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, then $x_ny_n\to xy$. Then as stated, use induction to prove that if $x_n^{(1)},\cdots,x_n^{(k)}\to x_1,\ldots,x_k$ respectively, $$x_n^{(1)}\cdots x_n^{(k)}\to x_1\cdots x_k$$

You already know the case $k=2$ is true!